# Vis.js - How can I get graph2d bar chart to display bars stretched to an end point?

Tags: javascript, bar-chart, vis.js

What I'm wanting to do is take the graph2d bar chart, and supply an X2 like the timeline control, and have the rectangle scale horizontally.

Using a graph2d:

```
var graph2d = new vis.Graph2d(container, items, groups, options);
```

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/wijgerden/vq4ezLgn/)

And have the bars auto fit [like this](http://almende.github.io/chap-links-library/js/timeline/examples/example19_bar_graph.html)

Anyone know how I can do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Feature [has been implemented](https://github.com/almende/vis/pull/2760) in vis.js and will be available in the upcoming version [v4.19.0](https://github.com/almende/vis/releases/tag/v4.19.0) of vis.js:

[image]